# Tomcat server distribution license key

Tags: java

I have a web application which is running on tomcat. I need to distribute it and install on many different servers. Some of these servers are not connected to the internet. I have to give this software to reseller companies who will install it in different locations.

Problem :: What is the best way I can keep track of how many machines my software is installed so that I know I am getting my licensing fee.

There are couple of approaches like 
1.  mac addr
2.  Key value

but both the above are very easy to crack.

thank you 
Firemonk

Answer (score 2):

If some of the machines will not be connected to the Internet, the version running on those machines cannot report back to you.

So there will be no solution that gives you an accurate count of the number of machines on which the software is installed.